# Iterate over two list and set element from first list

Tags: java, java-8

I have two `ArrayList` as below -

```
certificates=[CERT1, CERT2]
promotions=[{type}, {type, promotionCode}, {type, promotionCode}]
```

`promotions` list size is not confirm but `certificates` list size is confirmed. So consider first list size is 2 and second list size is 3

I want to set `promotionCode` in second list from `certificates` but in second list some time `promotionCode` is not present.

```
for (int i = 0; i < getCertificateNumber().size(); i++) {
   if (!promotions().isEmpty()) {
       promotions().get(i).setPromotionCode(getCertificateNumber().get(i));
   }
}
```

as in above `for loop` it set only first two promotions in `promotion list` because `certificate list` size two

How can I avoid any element from second list which don't have `promotionCode` and set CERT to element which has `promotionCode`

Comment: you can see my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement to check if the promotion code is not null , in this way to avoid getting beyong CERT1 :

```
int i = 0;
for ( Promotion prom : promotions ) {
    // check if promotioncode is not null
    if( prom.getPromotionCode() != null ) {
       prom.setPromotionCode(getCertificateNumber().get(i));
       i++; // increments only if not null
 }
}
```

Comment: if you add `null` check then you are missing first element `CERT1` and in next iteration `promotionCode` set as `CERT2` which should be `CERT1`

Comment: @ppb i edited the answer to solve this problem , the incrementation of "i" wont take place until the promotioncode is not empty

Answer (score 0):

This code will filter out promotions without codes and limit it to the number of certs we have. Then you can run your for loop to map the codes to valid promotions. Also, in this case I would run the for loop over `validPromotions`, not `certificates`, because we might not have any valid promotions.

```
    List<Promotion> validPromotions = promotions.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.promotionCode != null) // only keep promotions that have valid promotion codes
            .limit(certificates.length) // only keep as many promotions as we have certificates for
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```